# Query to Linked Server never stops executing

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle, linked-server

I have created a linked server in SQL Server 2005 to an Oracle DB.  When I run a query, The query never stops executing, and never returns results.  When I cancel the query, it never completes cancelling.  I have to close the window to get it to stop.

I have set things up as follows:

- Installed Oracle Client Tools on SQL Server
- Ran following query:

  `EXEC sp_addlinkedserver

     @server = 'MyNewLinkedServer',

     @srvproduct = 'Oracle',

     @provider = 'OraOLEDB.Oracle',

     @datasrc = 'TNSNAMES_Entry'`
- I then added the TNSNAMES.ORA file to `ORAHOME1\network\admin\` directory.
- In Properties for my Linked Server, I changed the Security settings to `Be made using this security context:` for all connections using my Oracle username/password
- I ran the following query:

  `SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MyNewLinkedServer, 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MySchema.MyTable');`

The query never completes execution.  Anyone have any insights?  Any steps I'm missing?

UPDATE:
I came in the following day and tried the query again and it worked just fine.  I suspect network issues of some sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on the Oracle server, querying v$session. See if you can see the remote connection, and what the Oracle session is doing. You can even do a trace on the Oracle side (set off by a login trigger) to record everything that happens (eg parse of query, returned errors etc).

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer even though the query just started working by itself.  Thanks for commenting.